# How To SELECT DISTINCT From Coma Seperated mysqli Query

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello Guys I have `coma separated entries` in my table. I want use `DISTINCT` function to get unique result. I have entries like

```
id | name
1  | sachin tendulkar, virat kohli, ms dhoni
2  | ms dhoni, vvs laxman, ajinkya rahane
3  | rohit sharma, virat kohli, ms dhoni
```

I want to use `mysqli` to show results like

```
name : sachin tendulkar, virat kohli, ms dhoni, 
       vvs laxman, ajinkya rahane, rohit sharma
```

I don't want to repeat these names if they are same.

I tried like :

```
$catquery = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM players WHERE id='$id';");
while($row2 = $catquery->fetch_object()):
echo "$row2->name";
endwhile;
```

But got result like :

```
sachin tendulkar, virat kohli, ms dhoni 
ms dhoni, vvs laxman, ajinkya rahane 
rohit sharma, virat kohli, ms dhoni
```

It's not finding unique names, please help me to get it solved !!!

Comment: If you are using PHP version less than 5.5, let me know to make the answer compatible with your version

Comment: @Mojtaba I am using php 5.5

Comment: So, you can easily use my answer

Comment: @Mojtaba 
 
Getting error like `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` when I add `$names = [];` line.

Comment: Are you using $names previously? Change my $names variable to something else like $unique_names. I updated the answer

Comment: Related: [PHP array - explode some comma separated elements into new items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476140/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to make one array and echo it one time

```
$unique_names = [];
$catquery = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM players WHERE id='$id';");
while($row2 = $catquery->fetch_object()):
  $unique_names = array_merge($unique_names, array_map('trim',explode(',',$row2->name)));
endwhile;

$unique_names = array_unique($unique_names);
echo implode(',',$unique_names);
```

At the end, you have all unique names in $unique_names array. For instance, I imploded it and echoed. You can use it in your own way

And this is added for your request in comment:

```
foreach($unique_names as $unique_name){
  echo '<a href="/player.php?player='. str_replace(' ','-',$unique_name) .'">'.$unique_name.'</a><br>';
}
```

Comment: I am not using $names previously

Comment: @Salim, So, you might put both answers together. Please use my answer independently. $names = []; just initials an empty array. Should not have any problem with stdClass

Comment: I tried your code independently, didn't got any error but got result like `Arijit Singh, Tulsi Kumar, Amaal Mallik,Ankit Tiwari, Arijit Singh ` There is two times `Arijit Singh` Not got filterd

Comment: @Salim, it could be because of spaces. I trimmed the arrays and uniqued them. Use the updated one

Comment: Thank You so much it worked <3 !!! Now please tell me one last thing how to link them separately like : `<a href="/player.php?player=arijit-singh">Arijit Singh</a>, <a href="/player.php?player=tulsi-kumar">Tulsi Kumar</a>, <a href="/player.php?player=amaal-mallik">Amaal Mallik</a>, <a href="/player.php?player=ankit-tiwari">Ankit Tiwari</a>`

Comment: @Salim, like what?

Comment: is it really possible ??

Comment: @Salim. Updated the answer

Comment: ! It's Worked Like a Champ !! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score" Sorry Buddy :/

Comment: @Salim. No problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to process it on PHP side.

```
$catquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM players WHERE id='$id';");

$names = [];    //Collect name to this
while($row2 = $catquery->fetch_object()) {
    $pieces = explode(',',$row2->name); //explode the string by ',' character
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        $names [] = trim($piece);
    }

}
var_dump(array_unique($names)); //here is the uniqe array
```

You can explode it by `,` (comma and space) if you are sure, there is always a space after comma.

If you just get back 1 row, because `id` is primary key, then no need the `while`.

Comment: Getting error like `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ` on `$names = [];` line

Comment: Fixed this `$row2->name`

Comment: It worked but getting one error `Notice: Undefined variable: row2 xyz.php on line 74

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xyz.php on line 74
array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "Navjot Singh" [1]=> string(11) "Ashiwin Kumar" [2]=> string(12) "Amaal Mallik" [3]=> string(12) "Ramesh Tiwari" } ` I added `$names = $row2->name;` as you said